# How to save data when edited in Table Inline in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, inline

So I have an editable table in my code and once I edit data and clic on ok the data is edited but one I refresh the page chnages r gone and not inserted in my database , if I check my browser's console I don't have problems or error, this my method update in my controller:

```
 public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            try {
                $fonction = Fonction::findOrFail($request->pk);
                $fonction->{$request->name} = $request->value;
                $fonction->save();

                return response()->json(['success' => true]);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
            }
        } else {
            dd('Update method called but not via AJAX');
        }
    }
```

this my table and my ajax script in my view:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Intitule fonction</th>
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($datas['f_perso'] as $fonc)
                                <tr>
                                    <td data-pk="{{ $fonc->id }}">{{ $fonc->intitule_fonction }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="flex align-items-center list-user-action">
                                            <form method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8" style="display:inline">
                                                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                                <button class="iq-bg-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Delete" ><i class="ri-delete-bin-line"></i></button>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/jquery-editable/css/jquery-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
                        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js" integrity="sha256-nQLuAZGRRcILA+6dMBOvcRh5Pe310sBpanc6+QBmyVM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

                        <script>$.fn.poshytip={defaults:null}</script>
                        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/jquery-editable/js/jquery-editable-poshytip.min.js"></script>
                        <script type="text/javascript">

                    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
                        }
                    });

                    $('#fonctions-table td:first-child').editable({
                        url: "{{ route('update') }}?t=" + new Date().getTime(),
                        type: 'text',
                        name: 'intitule_fonction',
                        pk: function() {
                            return $(this).closest('tr').data('id');
                        },
                        title: 'Enter Field',
                        error: function(error){
                        console.log(error)
                        alert("Service non sauvegardé");
                     }

                    });
                    </script>
```

this my Model:

```
class Fonction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'fonctions';
    protected $fillable = ['intitule_fonction', 'memo_fonction'];
}
```

and this is my routes

```
Route::post('/update', [FonctionController::class, 'update'])->name('update');
```

I tried to search on youtube, google chatgpt but nothing worked

Comment: Did you make sure code compile reach and enter `update` function? try to print logger($request->pk) and check logger file

Comment: Check in the `Network` tab after inspection. See if the ajax call executes after clicking OK & if it's executing then try to print the `$request->all()` in the first line of the method to see what data you're getting. Do step-by-step debugging.